# Alternative to ajax and form post when uploading image to server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, http-status-code-413

I'm using **summernote** text editor and the default behaviour when uploading a file is to **upload it as base64**. So i decided to store these images **in storage throught ajax and php**, but when i pushed the changes to production, image upload **failed becouse of Apache server configuration limiting ajax post to 50kb** images (*413 Request entity too large*).

Then i tried to make an extra button in the summernote panel to upload the files throught form post action, but the page itself is wrapped by another form, so **i can't nest it**.

The main problem is that the website is in a shared hosting and **i can't modify those apache values** and **they won't do it for me**.

So my question is: **Can i upload those images with something else?**

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this is not an ideal solution, but if the size limit is for ajax only, you could have an hidden iframe on the page that would submit a form on the fly to post the image? You can also get the result from the iframe too.

Comment: just make a wizzard and parse each step.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally solved this making a modal with a form in it! Thanks.